How to verify user password with HMACSHA512?
I'm trying to write a method to verify a user's password which has been generated using HMACSHA512. The method receives the password to verify along with the original password hash and salt which have been retrieved from the database.
Unfortunately, the ComputeHash() method creates a different hash than the one in the database, for the same password. What am I doing wrong?
private bool VerifyPasswordHash(string passwordToVerify, byte[] oldUserPasswordHash, byte[] existingPswSalt)
{
    bool isSame = false;

    using (HMACSHA512 hasher = new HMACSHA512(existingPswSalt))
    {
        // Generates a new hash which is different than the original
        byte[] pswHash = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordToVerify));

        isSame = pswHash.SequenceEqual(oldUserPasswordHash);
    }

    return isSame;
}

Here's the method which generated the original hash and the salt:
private (byte[] PswHash, byte[] PswSalt) CreatePasswordHashAndSalt(string password)
{
    byte[] pswSalt;
    byte[] pswHash;

    using (HMACSHA512 hmac = new HMACSHA512())
    {
        pswSalt = hmac.Key;
        pswHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
    }

    return (pswHash, pswSalt);
}


I used your code and I'm not able to replicate the issue, the salt generated by the second method, when used as input to the first, ends up calculating the same hash. How sure are you that you stored the hash and salt perfectly?

I check the first few bytes before and after writing to the database and they were the same (I didn't check all the bytes though).

The experiment you need to perform looks like this:
var results = yourObject.CreatePasswordHashAndSalt("somepassword");
bool isItWorking = yourObject.VerifyPasswordHash("somepassword", results.Item1, results.Item2);

and isItWorking should be true. If it is not true, then you found a bug in the tool you use. If it is working, then you will need to debug the way you get the password in the second case and whether it indeed matches the first as well as the hash and salt needs to be compared for consistency.
Debug your code carefully and find out which step deviates your values from those expected for the first time. Note that there could be white characters involved into typing in the password, which may cause variances you do not necessarily see. So I expect the experiment above to yield a true and if so, then you have made a mistake somewhere else.

I've extracted the two methods into a separate static class and wrote a unit test for them and it looks like they work correctly. Which makes me even more confused as I saw the password was the same every time when I was debugging the app. I've also added whitespace trimming for the password but it didn't help in my app.

@Val then the error was necessarily somewhere in the app, so you will need to very carefully debug it step-by-step in order to find out what the exact issue is. At some point one of your values becomes off. That's there the problem needs to be detected at. It is arduous and difficult to do so, but you should nevertheless be optimistic, as the unit test confirms that it's not the tool which had the bug. If this answer helped you in finding out what the issue is, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.
